# What is the purpose of a type lifetime bound?

Tags: rust

```
fn foo<'a, T>()
where T : 'a 
{
   //code a
}

fn foo()
{
   //code b
}
```

Where type T is any type with lifetime parameters.
What can be done in code a that can not be done in code b?

I expect them to be the exact same, because I dont understand the difference and what the lifetime bound is specifying. You can suggest additions to the first function if it makes explaining a use case easier (like parameters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the bound is required in the following code:

```
trait Elem {}

struct List<'a> {
    v: Vec<Box<dyn Elem + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a> List<'a> {
    fn push<T: Elem>(&mut self, t: T) {
        self.v.push(Box::new(t));
    }
}
```

```
error[E0309]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:9:21
  |
9 |         self.v.push(Box::new(t));
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...
  |
8 |     fn push<T: Elem + 'a>(&mut self, t: T) {
  |                     ++++
```

Essentially, a generic type may have any lifetime, but you sometimes need to use a generic type in a context where only specific lifetimes are allowed. In this case, `List<'a>` can only hold elements that live at least as long as `'a`. So the `T: 'a` constraint exists for those cases. `T: 'static` is the most common case for this syntax which conveys that the type may not contain any local references at all.

Comment: So this is in case Elem is any reference type, correct?

Comment: `Elem` is a *trait*, so the underlying type *might* be a reference or have references, but it also might not.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it will be used when a type wants to hold a reference to data it does not own.

I think [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) is probably a good example.

As the link shows, its full signature is:

```
pub enum Cow<'a, B>
where
    B: 'a + ToOwned + ?Sized,
{
    Borrowed(&'a B),
    Owned(<B as ToOwned>::Owned),
}
```

The lifetime parameter allows the struct to contain a reference to `B` without owning it. Since `Cow` is not the owner of `B` the borrow checker needs to be aware of how long `B` will live to prevent the reference `Cow` holds from ever dangling.

Comment: Removing the lifetime bound does not prompt a compilation error.  Why so? Something I struggle to understand is why you need the redundant 'a specifier if the reference already has it. Say for example B is a struct that has lifetime parameters and holds references- does passing it around by reference bind the lifetime of its parameters to the reference's lifetime? Or is that why we explicitly put the lifetime bound?

Comment: Yeah, be careful. The `B: 'a` is not actually required in this case because it is implied by `&'a B`. See this Q&A: [Does &'a T imply T: 'a?](/q/77025320/2189130). It is still there for legacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Other questions given examples of where an explicit bound is required, but do not answer the question in full generality.

The difference between `fn foo1<'a, T: 'a>() {...}` and `fn foo2<T>() {...}` is that, in `foo1`, you are capable of naming `'a`. In `foo2`, you cannot express *explicit* lifetime bounds that are related to `T`. The exact operations that are restricted by this constraint may change over time, because Rust may change implicit lifetime bounds implied by other constraints.

For instance, when you now mention `&'a T` somewhere in your code, you implicitly imply that `T: 'a`. This used not to be the case.